# What does this function calculate?

Tags: functions

Can anyone confirm to me what this function calculates?

```
Function m(t);
p=9t;
q=p+32;
r = q/5;
Return r;
End function
```

Ok so inputting numbers from $0-9$ (in numerical order) the output is as follows:
$$6.4,
8.2,
10,
11.8,
13.6,
15.4,
17.2,
19,
20.8,
22.6
$$
Ok so clearly each value is being incremented by $1.8$. But would it be correct to say that the function adds increments by $1.8$?

Comment: Please be consistent between lower and upper case.  If you divide by 5 before adding 32 you get the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Comment: Sorry about the format. Yes I get the conversion for Celsius into Fahrenheit. This is why i am confused when i am being asked what this code calculates.

Comment: When the 32 is divided by 5, it takes Celsius and returns Fahrenheit-25.6.  I don't think there is a better characterization than Alexander Gruber has given.

Answer (score 2):

$M(t)=\frac{9t+32}{5}$ is the equation of a line with slope $9/5=1.8$ and $y$-intercept $32/5=6.4$.

Comment: As a result, the rate of change of $M(t)$ is constant and is $9/5=1.8$

Comment: Ok so would i be right in saying: "This code calculates a constant rate of change of M(t) by 9/5 (1.8)"? As an answer to "Confirm what the code calculates"? I have this written down but just doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @Fendorio No.  This code calculates the height of the line with the equation I wrote above as a function of $t$.  It's just a linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

So, we simplify the calculation to one-line equation $$r=\frac{9t+32}{5}$$

to find the  increment, we separate the division, and do the division, which is $$r = \frac{9}{5}t + \frac{32}{5}$$ $$r = 1.8t + 6.4$$

and with $1.8t$, we can prove that the answer was incremented 1.8 when t incremented by 1

EDIT: if we use "Equation of a Straight Line" formula where $y = mx + b$ (or $y = mx + c$ in UK), we can use this formula to form a graph $y = 1.8x + 6.4$, where $m=1.8$, $b=6.4$

Answer (score 1):

r = q/5 $\rightarrow$ r = (p + 32)/5 $\rightarrow$ r = (9t + 32)/5

Hence r = 9/5t + 32/5

equation of line is y = mx + b, so as we can see this is just equation of line of slope 9/5 and y-intercept of 32/5.

Answer (score 0):

Just work through the formula:

$r = \frac{q}{5} = \frac{p+32}{5} = \frac{9t+32}{5}$. It multiplies by 9, adds 32 and divides by 5. Or it multiplies by 0.18 and adds 6.4.